# Arduino microprocesssor programming

Tags: arduino, microprocessors

I want to do microprocessor programming like we do in intel 8086 processor by using DOS & TASM.
This gives access to register like AX BX etc.
how can i use in arduino ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking for is Arduino assembly programming. That is too big of a topic to cover here, but you can start by looking [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/AVR), [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/inline_asm.html) and [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Command-Line-Assembly-Language-Programming-for-Ard/).